# Laravel access session data inside web.php

Tags: php, laravel

I can't use localization prefix because of my client's needs. I'm trying to store locale data into session and group my routes based on that 'locale'. But i cant access session data inside web.php.

```
$locale = Session::get('locale');

    if($locale == 'tr') {
       Route::get('/kurumsal/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CorporateController@index')->name('corporate');
    } elseif ($locale == 'eng){
       Route::get('/corporate/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CorporateController@index')->name('corporate');
    }
```

LanguageController middleware

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function index($locale = ''){
        if ($locale == '') {
            Session::put('locale', 'eng');
        } else {
            Session::put('locale', $locale);
        }
         return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to conditionally set routes if there's no conflicts.

The following works just fine:

```
Route::get('/kurumsal/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CorporateController@index')->name('corporate');
Route::get('/corporate/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CorporateController@index')->name('corporate');
```

If you want to restrict non-localised routes from being accessed then you do need session access but you can have that via [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) e.g.:

```
class LocaleRestricted {

     public function handle($request, $next, ...$localesAllowed) {
          if (!in_array(Session::get('locale'), $localesAllowed)) {
              abort(404, 'This route is not available for this locale');
          }
          return $next($request);  
     }
}
```

You then need to register this locale in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
// ...
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   // ...
   'locale_restricted' => LocaleRestricted::class
];
```

Then you can use it as:

```
$locale = Session::get('locale');

Route::middleware('locale_restricted:tr')->group(function () {
       Route::get('/kurumsal/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CorporateController@index')->name('corporate');
});
Route::middleware('locale_restricted:eng')->group(function () {

       Route::get('/corporate/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CorporateController@index')->name('corporate');
});
```

Comment: Well that was much easier than i thought. By the way, is there any way to setLocale based on my routes ? Because if anyone just go for siteurl.com/corporate he'll see Turkish translations because default locale is set to 'tr'.

Comment: You can use the above solution with the middleware but do `setLocale` instead of doing the `abort` (note that `$locale` is an array so you'd probably need to use `$locale[0]??'default locale value'` (where default locale value is what you want the default to be in case you ever use the middleware without specifying it)

Answer (score 1):

For Get Data from session you can use

```
$value = $request->session()->get('your-key-name');
```

But I'm not sure It works in Web.php or not..!! But you can use this one in Controller, Middelware etc many more places.

For More Details See [Laravel Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#the-global-session-helper)